# Not able to Select, Copy & Paste in Textbox

Tags: javascript, jquery

I restrict user to enter only number in textbox through javascript, but i face a problem that not able to perform select,copy & paste through keyboard.

Here is Code:-

```
 if ((event.keyCode >= 48 && event.keyCode <= 57) || (event.keyCode >= 96 && event.keyCode <= 105) || event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 190 || event.keyCode == 110) {
        } else {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
        if (($(this).val().indexOf('.') !== -1 && event.keyCode == 190) || $(this).val().indexOf('.') !== -1 && event.keyCode == 110)//Allow only one time decimal to input
            event.preventDefault();
    });
```

[Jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ANJYR/kzw4LpvL/)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#txtboxToFilter").keydown(function (e) {
        // Allow: backspace, delete, tab, escape, enter and .
        if ($.inArray(e.keyCode, [46, 8, 9, 27, 13, 110, 190]) !== -1 ||
            // Allow: Ctrl+A, Command+A
            (e.keyCode === 65 && (e.ctrlKey === true || e.metaKey === true)) || 
            // Allow: home, end, left, right, down, up
            (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40)) {
             // let it happen, don't do anything
             return;
        }
        // Ensure that it is a number and stop the keypress
       if ((e.shiftKey || (e.keyCode < 48 || e.keyCode > 57)) && (e.keyCode < 96 || e.keyCode > 105)) {
           e.preventDefault();
       }
   });
});
```

or use this for copy, cut and paste by keyboard

```
 $(function() {$('#staticParent').on('keydown', '#child', function(e)-1!==$.inArray(e.keyCode,46,8,9,27,13,110,190])||/65|67|86|88/.test(ekeyCode)&&(!0===e.ctrlKey||!0===e.metaKey)||35<=e.keyCode&&40>=e.keyCode||e.shiftKey||48>e.keyCode||57<e.keyCode)&&(96>e.keyCode||105<e.keyCode)&&e.preventDefault()});
```

})

```
<div id="staticParent">
   <input id="child" type="textarea" />
</div>
```